# Template specializations in friend declarations post C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, template-specialization, friend

**Context:** To our surprise, MSVC with C++20 mode and two-phase compliance enabled accepts the following code:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    friend int foo<X>(X x);

    int a = 10;
};

template <class T>
int foo(T t)
{
    return t.a;
}

int main()
{
    return foo(X<float>{});
}
```

This compiles/links and returns `10` in MSVC and gcc (but clang barks): https://godbolt.org/z/98cd7v7a6.

Those who know about two-phase lookup will find that this looks pretty crazy - we can somehow befriend a template specialization before the corresponding template is even declared. Looks and sounds very wrong. And indeed, for earlier C++ versions, all compilers would immediately reject it: https://godbolt.org/z/M1733EPd5

But it appears that the following wording in C++20 paves the way for this (or at least makes it not outright ill-formed from the start): https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#2.sentence-4 (emphasis mine)

> A name is also considered to refer to a template if it is an unqualified-id followed by a `<` and name lookup either finds one or more functions **or finds nothing**.

Now, this leads to a whole host of... well, absurd corner cases. Note that outside of `friend` declarations you'd have to begin a template specialization with `template<>`, but that is not the case in `friend` declarations. Predictably, compilers cannot even remotely agree on what is now legal and what is not:

| Befriend... | godbolt | MSVC | gcc | clang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ...declaration of specialization of non-existent function template inside a class, call it | https://godbolt.org/z/9bczs6nde | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ |
| ...declaration of specialization of non-existent function template inside an uninstantiated class *template* | https://godbolt.org/z/461h774sz | ✓ | ✓ | ✗ |
| ...declaration of specialization of non-existent function template inside a class *template*, call it (note https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inject) | https://godbolt.org/z/fK6s9aj5G | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ |
| ...declaration of specialization of non-existent function template specialization in class, provide function template definition, call it | https://godbolt.org/z/Mevr4EWzG | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ |
| ...declaration of specialization of non-existent function template specialization in class *template*, provide function template definition, call it | https://godbolt.org/z/d9s9hWsa7 | ✓ | ✓ | ✗ |
| ...*definition* of specialization of previously declared function template inside a class, call it | https://godbolt.org/z/ebrhvGrM4 | ICE | ✗ | ✓ |
| ...*definition* of specialization of previously declared function template inside a class *template*, call it | https://godbolt.org/z/bsjKxWYco | ✗ | ✗ | ✓ |
| ...*definition* (!) of specialization of non-existent (!!) function template inside a class template and call it afterwards (!!!) | https://godbolt.org/z/PnP6oKrrM | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ |

In short, wtf.

**Question:** Does the C++20 standard currently have a clear and consistent stance on these points:

1. Is it legal for friend declarations to refer to a not-previously-declared function template? Does this depend on whether we are inside a template/involve dependent types?
2. Is it ever (or always?) legal to *define* a specialization of a function template via a friend declaration? (See again https://godbolt.org/z/bTaYraP6j, https://godbolt.org/z/Y7qf6PPxY - some compilers state it's illegal but then also randomly accept it)

Comment: @Afshin FWIW, the standard appears to more or less acknowledge what you say in this note: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#2.sentence-2. But I have no clear concept of how ADL applies to this whole situation around `friend`, and it appears that the compilers do not either.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the reason for the changed lookup rule was that - equally absurd - a totally unrelated local foo template would trigger an ADL search to find the one actually used. But without the local foo `foo<x` was an error.

Comment: _https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#2.sentence-4 ... Cursory search points to this paper being the origin of that: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html_ A document [Generated on 2020-04-03](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/) got its wording from an October 23, 2020 paper? Where «A name is also considered to refer to a template if it» is being removed? Seriously?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I admit it was *very* cursory. Removed that part from the question.

Comment: According to the answer in the Clang issue https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46865, a declaration of a template named `foo` prior to the `friend` declaration of the specialization is required even in C++20 mode. (Note that the issue had been raised much later than the relevant change to the standard draft was made, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/75516dac895d8a9ab7a925b8400989910e3b08ff). So that would mean Clang is correct to reject all of these cases. I am not sure how to get to this conclusion though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s true that there are no **parsing** difficulties here: C++20 does give the right meaning to the `<`, and template argument lists are parsed independently of the template declaration (which is how function template overloading and ADL can work).

Next, C++20 as published doesn’t say much in general about the process of **declaration matching**, leaving a number of questions open about which declarations refer to the same entity (validly or no).  As such, it doesn’t really address the friend-before-declaration case, although its [namespace.memdef]/3 says

> If the name in a friend declaration is neither qualified nor a *template-id* and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace.

which implies that there is some sort of **lookup** performed, including in the *template-id* case, that could fail.

I say “as published” in the above because many of the fixes in the already-mentioned P1787R6 were considered to be Defect Reports (read: retroactive).  I don’t recall an issue on specifically this subject, but the changes in that paper to **[decl.meaning]** to specify the special lookup process for declared names might best be considered retroactive as well.

As for **defining** a specialization, the only thing that any recent standard version says is in [temp.expl.spec]/1:

> An explicit specialization […] can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>`; […]

This is unfortunately vague, but it’s not unreasonable to take as an implication that there is no other means of defining an explicit specialization, including via a friend declaration.  Certainly that’s the intent: specializations aren’t found by **name lookup**, so there’s no point in making them hidden friends.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't checked C++20, but I think the latest draft standard says that the declaration of `friend int foo<X>(X x);` is ill-formed .

[[dcl.meaning]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#general-2):

> If the declaration is a friend declaration:
>
> - If the *id-expression* `E` in the *declarator-id* of the *declarator* is a *qualified-id* or a *template-id*:
>
>   - [...]
>   - The *declarator* shall correspond to one or more declarations found by the lookup

In `friend int foo<X>(X x);`, the *id-expression* in the *declarator-id* is `foo<X>`. It is a *template-id*, so it is required to have a preceding declaration.

(For the reference, `foo` is looked up from the definition point ([[temp.res.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#1)), because it is not a dependent name ([[temp.dep.general]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.general#2.sentence-2)).)

Comment: The quoted passage originates from https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html. Unfortunately I wasn't really able to determine whether the same restriction was already present in some other way in C++20 or whether this is a newly-added (maybe as a resolution of one of the listed issues?).